# windows web server 2008 IIS7 keeps rediricting

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

In IIS7 I right click on the site and choose "Switch to content view" then add a text file called test.txt right click again and switch to features view. Double click the http redirect icon and see it's not forwarding.

Right click the site and switch to content view again now right click on test.txt and choose browse only to be forwarded to some other site that gives me 404 for not having /test.txt.

I don't know where to look anymore as the settings mentioned above would indicate there would be no forwarding but opening the file proves that it does.

When using forcecors plugin for firefox and making a ajax request to the text file I can see the response header: `Location http://some_other_site/test.txt`.

Hope it's something simple.

**[update]**

In the application I checked out the settings under "Url rewrite" and found a rule that redirects. Removed this rule and stopped started IIS but it's still forwarding. Could not find anything under System32\inetsvr\config that would indicate redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the url rewrite rule and testing in the browser it kept on forwarding because I think my browser remembered it was moved. Cache settings on IIS should check if file has changed after it was last cached (I think last modified headers) but somehow a redirect works differently. Did not clear my browser cache and even doing that could still cause a problem with proxies caching it.

What I did was opening it this way:

```
http://develop.mysite.com/test.txt?refresh=newValue
```

Like magic I wasn't redirected and it works now. Start FF with another profile and see if that solves the problem as the new profile should not be aware of the sites response being "permanently moved" by a previous request.